# Ordering FFMPEG Elements

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'm working on FFMPEG with Jetson nano and PC.
I want to know the ordering element of FFMPEG can be effect in the result? Is it necessory to observe the ordering of elements?

In the concept of decoding and encoding streams:

> ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_nvdec -c:v h264_cuvid -i input -c:v
>   h264_nvenc output

If I replace the **-hwaccel cuvid** with **-c:v h264_nvdec**, such as:

> ffmpeg -c:v h264_nvdec -c:v h264_cuvid -hwaccel cuvid -i input -c:v
>   h264_nvenc output

Q1- May be these two above commands corecttly run, but in the backgrand these two commands have same operations and results?

Q2 -Or if I want to put **-hwaccel cuvid** after **-i input**, are these two commands have same operations and results?

Comment: Yes, order of inputs is important: `ffmpeg [global options] [input options] -i input [output options] output`. Options in `[input options]` are applied to the input. Options in `[output options]` are applied to the output.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what's meaning here: ffmpeg [inputs] -i input -c copy -f rawvideo, -c copy what's do here, what's meaning -f rawvideo, when i don't use -c copy, usage of cpu is high, why?

Comment: `-c copy` enables [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode. `-f rawvideo` is used to manually select the rawvideo muxer.

Comment: if I set decoder option and also use -c copy in the output_options, then It only effecte in the encoder stage or omid the decoder stage? I want to use a command that the decoded input passed to the output without encoding, Is it corect to use -c copy in the output_options?

Comment: Refer to the link in my previous comment.